# Receive a JSONObject that has an array and fill a ListView

Tags: java, php, android, web-services

```
<?php
// DEVOLVE TODAS AS PESSOAS COM TODA A INFO
$app->get('/api/pessoas', function () {
    require_once('db/dbconnect.php');
    $myArray = array();
    foreach($db->pessoa()
            ->order("id")
            as $row){
        array_push($myArray, array('nome' => $row["nome"], 'idade' => 
$row["idade"]));
        $result = ['status' => true, 'data' => $myArray];
    }
    if(isset($result)){
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }else{
        echo "Não existem resultados";
    }
});
```

this is the web service I am using and it's giving me the correct answer of every person in the db with all attributes

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"nome":"Paulo","idade":"23"},{"nome":"Manuela","idade":"23"},{"nome":"Paulo2","idade":"25"},{"nome":"Maranhao Faria","idade":"888"}]}
```

Now, I want to receive it in Java and fill a list with it:

```
public class ListInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_info);

    String url = "paulomaranhao.000webhostapp.com/myslim/api/pessoas";

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try{
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("data");
                        List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            items.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ListInfo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(adapter);
                    }catch(JSONException e){}
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListInfo.this, getResources().getString(R.string.errorShowing), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT). show();
                    return;
                }
            });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

When I debug it does not even enter the onResponse. 
After that I want to fill the list, if possible customized, or just with the name of the person.

Thank you so much!!!

---

Solved my problem! I was adding it to the queue, MySingleton, but it was not initialized in the begining. It was just missing this RequestQueue declaration :

```
private RequestQueue queue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rest_post);

    queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).
            getRequestQueue();
}
```

Comment: have you added internet permission in manifest?

Comment: does your `addToRequestQueue` only add task to queue or check if queue is being processed?

Comment: check if your URL is correct and it is get request

Comment: Your url should start with http or https.

Answer (score 0):

The internet permission is added and working as the other points because I already have two different activities working properly, one that inserts a person on the db and one that gets the info of a person by id, and all of that works. Also the URL in the browser is correct